# How to join when condition is true?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT 
     *
    FROM   data_entity a
        LEFT JOIN list_dokumen b ON a.dokumen = b."id"
            CASE WHEN b.pengirim_level == 1
                            THEN LEFT JOIN master_polda c ON c.id_polda = b.pengirim_level_id
                     WHEN b.pengirim_level == 2
                            THEN LEFT JOIN master_polres d ON d.id_polres = b.pengirim_level_id
                     WHEN b.pengirim_level == 3
                            THEN LEFT JOIN master_polsek e ON e.id_polsek = b.pengirim_level_id
                     WHEN b.pengirim_level == NULL
                            THEN NULL
            END
```

Comment: I don't think you can construct SQL based on conditions.

Comment: I think your SQL could be written more beautiful and concise only if you can clarify your requirement clearer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct SQL based on conditions inside PL/pgSQL function using dynamic sql. See [PL/pgSQL EXEC documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Or you can just join all three tables and use `coalesce` to get necessary fields from one of them.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, coalesce(c.FIELD, d.FIELD, e.FIELD)
FROM data_entity a
LEFT JOIN list_dokumen b ON a.dokumen = b."id"
LEFT JOIN master_polda c ON b.pengirim_level == 1 AND c.id_polda = b.pengirim_level_id
LEFT JOIN master_polres d ON b.pengirim_level == 2 AND d.id_polres = b.pengirim_level_id
LEFT JOIN master_polsek e ON b.pengirim_level == 3 AND e.id_polsek = b.pengirim_level_id
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can rewrite your query as:

```
        SELECT * FROM   data_entity a 
                    LEFT JOIN list_dokumen b  ON a.dokumen = b."id"
                    LEFT JOIN master_polda c  ON c.id_polda = b.pengirim_level_id and b.pengirim_level = 1
                    LEFT JOIN master_polres d ON d.id_polres = b.pengirim_level_id and b.pengirim_level == 2
                    LEFT JOIN master_polsek e ON e.id_polsek = b.pengirim_level_id and b.pengirim_level == 3
            END
```